# IdentityServer3 bypassing the consents screen

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I'd like to bypass the consents screen when a user logs in using IdentityServer3, granting all consents by default. Is there an way to configure this?

This is the screen I wish to bypass:

[image: IdentityServer3 authorize permissions screen]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When configuring a `Client` its `RequireConsent` property should be set to `false`.